# How to programatically extract function names, function arguments and strings from a .NET binary?

Tags: windows, tools, .net, decompiler

My goal is to

1. extract function names,
2. the libraries they come from (if the functions were imported),
3. function arguments, and
4. strings

from a .NET binary. How can I do this?
Is this possible using tools like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)
or [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)? Do they offer an API that allows to do this?

I noticed IDA's Function Window is populated, but the Strings Window is not. In addition, I guess it would be easier (e.g. to get function arguments) to use a tool that does decompilation...

PS:
The code is not obfuscated, it is not malware but regular software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib), used by the very powerful [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy) (.net disassembler), is an open source .net library to analyse .net modules & assemblies which may be what you are looking for.

They also have an example similar to your use case:

[Opens mscorlib.dll and then prints out all types in the assembly, including the number of methods, fields, properties and events each type has.](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib/blob/master/Examples/Example1.cs)

Answer (score 0):

A while back i wrote this cheapo dependency tool. It's on my GitHub. https://github.com/marshalcraft/CheapoDllDependencyTool?files=1